# How to properly exclude springboot-actuator in pom.xml

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Actuator  still shows my application health info even after being excluded in the pom.xml

tried following the official doc here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html

but still unable to disable it, here is my pom

```
<build>
    <finalName>my-app/finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator
                        </artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

i expect my app's health info wont be displayed anymore, but it is still showing when accessed in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Don't use exclusions inside `<plugin>` declaration, it has nothing with dependencies that get packaged into the resulting artifact

Instead find the `<dependencies>` section; spring actuator should appear there.

Just remove the dependency on the actuator.

The best way to check that maven didn't include the jar is to check the content of `BOOT-INF/lib` of the compiled spring boot application

If the build process is complicated and you don't know exactly where does the actuator come from, try to use `mvn dependency:tree` on your pom, it will should the path to the actuator

Once you figure out that spring boot actuator comes from groupId=X and artifactId=Y, you should exclude it in your pom.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>X</groupId>
        <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <exclusions> 
          <exclusion>__here__comes__
                  actuator_groupId_and_artifact_id__
          </exclusion> 
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ...
 </dependencies>
```

Comment: no,  i dont have it in the dependencies, i only have spring-boot-starter-web, spring-cloud-starter-zuul  and spring-boot-starter-security

Comment: so you say that there is no actuator jars in BOOT-INF/lib ? In this case actuator can't be initialized...

Comment: yes, there are actuator jars, spring-boot-actuator and spring-boot-starter-actuator, im not sure why its there when i havent added them in maven dependencies

Comment: That's why I've suggested to run mvn dependency:tree in the directory where your pom resides. Please read carefully my answer :)

Comment: i already know where the actuator is coming from, my problem is how to remove it

Comment: deleting the jars manually fix this, but this is not a good solution

Comment: If it comes from dependency with a groupId X and artifactId Y you should add the following into the pom of your project: <dependencies><dependency><groupId>X</groupId><artifactId>Y</artifactId><version>...</version><exclusions><exclusion>__here__comes__actuator_groupId_and_artifact_id__</exclusion> </dependency> Bottom Line you're right, exclusions is the way to go here, but  you didn't use them correctly

Comment: well can you point me a documentation that i can follow to do it correctly?

Comment: I think my last comment pretty much explains it. I've updated the answer anyway

Comment: i already know that excludes is the solution, you can also see it in my sample code, hence the subject of the post, what im trying to figure out is why its not working

Comment: You exclude the actuator inside the "plugin" section of xml in the sample code, and I say that its wrong... Please read again my answer. If you put exclude in "plugin" section => it won't work. If you put "exclude" inside "dependencies" section it works.

Comment: i already read your anwser and nothing worked, thanks though, will probably just remove the jars manually